# Using Javascript to return a single value to HTML from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've had a look around at 2 or three different ways to do this, however I'm still encountering problems.

With the below I can generate an alert, but nothing gets written to the div

**JSON**

```
{
    "FixVersion": "Version - 1.2.3",
    "BugCount": "27",
    "TaskCount": "4",
    "StoryCount": "5"
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT ATTEMPT 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function read_project_title() {

      $.getJSON("ProjectVersion.json", function(data) {

        alert(data["FixVersion"]);
        return(data["FixVersion"]);   

      });

    }
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT ATTEMPT 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function read_project_title() {

      $.getJSON("ProjectVersion.json", function(data) {
         var node = document.getElementById('pageTitle');
         node.innerHTML(data["FixVersion"]);
      });

    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="pageTitle"><script>read_project_title();</script></div>
```

Comment: Try data.FixVersion instead of data["FixVersion"]

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi, just tried it. No result in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried this way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageTitle"></div>
        <script>
            function read_project_title() {
                $.getJSON("ProjectVersion.json", function(data) {

                    var node = document.querySelector('#pageTitle');
                    if (node) {
                        node.innerHTML = data.FixVersion;
                    }
                 });
             }

             read_project_title();
         </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. If I put it in the head as script it also works. Fixed. Thanks. The issue was my previous `var node` and `node.innerHTML` declarations

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function read_project_title() {

      $.getJSON("ProjectVersion.json", function(data) {

        alert(data.FixVersion);
        return(data.FixVersion);   

      });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: The alert works, but still nothing is written to html

Comment: yeah, you have to include .html(data.Fixversion) to make it work

Answer (score 0):

In your second attempt, simply change the line node.innerHTML(data["FixVersion"]); to:

```
node.innerHTML = data["FixVersion"];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**simple fix!** just print out all returned data to make sure you're getting what you expect

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/d42b293d42cd9833696c5d4b19709f2e)

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('objects.json',function(data) {
    $('#pageTitle').html(data['FixVersion']);
    
    // print data
    document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
  });
});
```